# Can't get element from array in second column PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, select

I made two dimensional array as timestamp type. Then i added an insert like this

```
'{{2017-03-01 14:00:00},{2017-06-01 21:00:00}}'
```

How can I get only second element?

Creating of table:

```
create table client(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, full_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, gender VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, phone_number VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, card_type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, card_period Timestamp[][] NOT NULL );
```

Then I made some inserts as next:

```
insert into client (full_name, phone_number, card_type, card_period, gender) values('Mr James Abrams','3805832940003073','Bronze','{{2017-03-01 14:00:00},{2017-06-01 21:00:00}}','man');
```

When for example I select something

```
select card_period from client where id = 1;
```

Its shows like: 2017-03-01T14:00:00,2017-06-01T21:00:00
I tried to select card_period[0:1] - shows only first, if [0:2] then it shows them both

Comment: How you get the first one? Show db schema? How you insert that string?

Comment: BTW [Range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer already given before me is correct in format, just number of array order are wrong :)

This is how you get 2nd element value:

```
SELECT card_period[2][1] FROM client WHERE id = 1;
     card_period
---------------------
 2017-06-01 21:00:00
(1 row)
```

Comment: oh, it's crazy xD. Thank you

Comment: That is crazy, what sintaxis you use if want add two rows? like [here](http://rextester.com/QXOUZ98662) ?

Comment: The syntax is not IMHO crazy if you create 2-dimensional array, then this is common syntax in any programming language to read 1 dimension element and then 2nd dimension element :)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT column_name[1][2] FROM the_table`

Comment: Well then the problem is someplace else, because that is how you access one array. We need more info.

Comment: Updated my question